# Объекты типа ContactInformation остаются только в последней записи в бд?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
     class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            using (ContactContext db = new ContactContext())
            {
                List<ContactInformation> conInformList= new List<ContactInformation>();
                ContactInformation ContactInformation1 = new ContactInformation
                {
                    Another = "8",
                    ContactId = 0,
                    Email = "8",
                    Id = 0,
                    Phone = "8",
                    Skype = "89",
                };
                conInformList.Add(ContactInformation1);
                //ContactInformation1.CreareContactInformation(Contact1);

                Contact Contact1 = new Contact
                {
                    Id = 0,
                    Name = "Вася",
                    SurName = "Пупкин",
                    MiddleName = "Николаевич",
                    BirthDate = "1.11.1990",
                    Organization = "Купол",
                    Position = "programmer",
                    ContInforms = conInformList,
                };

                // добавляем их в бд
                db.Contacts.Add(Con
                //Contact contact2 = db.Contacts
                //    .Where(o => o.Id == 1)
                //    .FirstOrDefault();
                //db.Contacts.Remove(contact2);
tact1);
        //        db.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Объекты успешно сохранены");

                // получаем объекты из бд и выводим на консоль
                var users = db.Contacts;
                Console.WriteLine("Список объектов:");
                foreach (Contact c in users)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1} - {2} - {3} - {4} - {5} - {6} - {7}", c.Id, c.Name, c.SurName, c.MiddleName, c.Organization, c.Position, c.BirthDate, c.ContInforms);
                }


            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

public class ContactInformation 
    {
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Skype { get; set; }
        public string Another { get; set; }

        public virtual Contact Contact {get;set;}

    }

public class Contact
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SurName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName {get;set;}
        public string BirthDate {get;set;}
        public string Organization {get;set;}
        public string Position {get; set;}

        public virtual ICollection<ContactInformation> ContInforms { get; set; }

    }

public ContactContext()
            :base("MyBase")
        { }
        // Это свойство ссылается на таблицу в базе данных
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ContactInformation> ContInform { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContactInformation>().HasRequired(p => p.Contact)
                .WithMany(b => b.ContInforms)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ContactId);
            modelBuilder.Ignore<ContactInformation>();  
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ээээ вы о чем вообще? У вас ContactInformation - коллекция, вы её даже не попытались развернуть.

Comment: @Monk То есть, Как?

Comment: foreach (Contact c in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1} - {2} - {3} - {4} - {5} - {6}", c.Id, c.Name, c.SurName, c.MiddleName, c.Organization, c.Position, c.BirthDate);
    foreach (var s in c.ContInforms)
      Console.WriteLine(" - {0}.{1} - {2} - {3} - {4}", s.Id, s.Phone, s.Email, s.Skype, s.Another);
}